# Using Chartkick, I got the first part of my solution working, need to have multiple bars in a chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I have my chart populating the hours in a project, the issue I am having is displaying each project name without having to hard code them, and then discern the hours between the two, say A has 3 hours and B has 4 I am trying to display each on a different bar.

My View looks like this:

```
<h3>Home</h3>

<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>

<% @projects.each do |project| %>
<% @time_entries_list = project.time_entries.where(user_id:
@user.id).sort_by       &:work_date %>   
<% @time_entries_list.each do |time_item| %>
<% @time_total += time_item.hours %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<%= bar_chart({"test" => @time_total, "test2" => @time_total}) %>
```

and my controller looks like this

```
 class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
     @users = User.all
     @time_entries_list = [] 
     @time_total = 0 
    @user = current_user 
   @projects = Project.all 
  end
 end
```

Hope I can find some help! 
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where to start with helping you on your current code. You have alot of logic in the view that should be in the controller and all the objects you are instantiating (`@time_entries_list`, `@users`, `@user`, `@time_total`, `@projects` are not really needed (as far as I can see)

I would recommend a better understanding of both ruby and rails before trying to take on something like this but as for a better methodology you could try this:(Note I have never used chart kick I just went of the documentation)

Controller Code:

```
    class HomeController < ApplicationController
        def index   
          @time_entries = current_user.time_entries.joins(:project).
              select("sum(time_entries.hours) as total_hours,
                      projects.name as project_name").
              group("projects.name")
          @project_times = @time_entries.map do |time_entry|
                {
                  name: time_entry.project_name,
                  data: time_entry.total_hours
                }
            end + [{
                    name:'Total',
                    data: @time_entries.inject(0){|sum,entry| sum += entry.total_hours}
                  }]

        end
     end
```

View Code:

```
<%= bar_chart(@project_times) %>
```

I think that should do it. It should in theory create a bar chat for the current user showing the time they worked on each project and the total time they worked on all projects which seemed to be your end goal but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: This worked and I know why now, thank you very much. I am in an internship and learning on the go but thank you for this

Comment: @Weisbrod22 there is no better way to learn than to do. glad I could help. just remember especially when creating charts only select the exact data you need and make SQL do the heavy lifting. Also as a rule of thumb the view should not have to do much more than display the data, the controller should just get the information and the model should store and supply it.

Comment: I will remember that as I move forward, thank you very much!